# iTextSharp.text.Document to byte[]

Tags: serializable

**Hi,
     I have created a pdf document using iTextSharp, While the document is in memory, I want to make it as byte[] so that i can convert it as attachment to mail. I tried with the following code.**

```
private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)//passed iTextSharp document as object
{
    if (obj == null)
        return null;
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

I am getting the following error.

Type 'iTextSharp.text.Document' in Assembly 'itextsharp, Version=5.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca' is not marked as serializable.

How to overcome this?